# Can someone explain me this infinitesimal analysis method?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I am reading the Numerical Algorithms book by Justin Solomon. But I can't understand this method:
[Mathematics Review - Page 16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eepOL.jpg)

Can someone explain to me how we can get the third line based on what we've gained in the second line? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: The author just added $0=yf'(x)-yf'(x)$ and rearranged.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the third line they have $y\int_x^y f''(t)dy- \int_x^y tf''(t)dt$
$= \int_x^y yf''(t)dt- \int_x^y tf''(t)dt$

$= \int_x^y (yf''(t)dt- tf''(t)dt)$

$= \int_x^y (y- t)f''(t)dt$